# DropDown List issue in yii

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

help me out with this issue.
Am using yii.

I have a column called imei in my table -> Mob

Now in my view I have created 3 activedropdown lists based on same field imei on same table -> Mob.

but values are different, i.e I have grouped some ten values in each drop down list.

So user can select any option from any dropdown list and it will be processed.

Problem is when I click button for post action it is taking only last drop downlist value and if last list value is not selected then it is passing null value.

Ex: My 'A' dropdownlist contains 1,2,3
My 'B'  dropdownlist contain 4,5,6

When I do post action and access through model->imei am getting only 'B' drop down list values.

What I need is to get the value of selected option irrespective of order. if 'A' list value is selected then 'A'.

if both are selected then 'B'. priority from lower to higher.

Can you gives help me out how to acheive this?

Hope Am clear to you ppl or is it wrong approach? tell me the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have set the names of both of drop down lists were, then the form has been submitted, the value of last field that has duplicated name would be posted.

Workaround: You can set separated name for each drop down list like example below

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Categories[A][]', '', $listData1, array('empty' => '(Select a category', '')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Categories[B][]', '', $listData2, array('empty' => '(Select a category', '')); ?>
```

Once the form is submitted, you are able to access those `POST` values in array

```
array 
  'Categories' => 
    array 
      'A' => 
        array 
          0 => string '1' (length=1) // selected value of drop down A
      'B' => 
        array
          0 => string '5' (length=1) // selected value of drop down B
```

Depend on the strategy that you want (which priority more), you can process them after then.

Comment: echo CHtml::activeDropDownList('A','', $model->getCategories(),
                        array('prompt'=> 'Please Select')); I tried like this but its giving me error 
Error 500
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: sorry I dint mention am getting values from database so am using active dropdownlist

Comment: What I supposed to change just about their name. When you use active drodownlist, you can use setAttributes and value has been set automatically for you, but in your case, there required more custom for category, matter thing is you have to capture the selected value of both of drop down list and process them. You just replace the these drop down lists with new one, submit and dump POST to see what it would return

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are using the same field for three drop downs. Try change the order of the drop down in your form and post the data. I think then it will post the last drop down value in your form. The reason is that the last drop down value is overriding the previously selected values. Just a guess only.